# SharePoint list NewForm.aspx - remove link

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I have found an old, unused list and noticed that its NewForm.aspx contains a link in the top right corner. The associated span element is named "PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead". It contains the following markup:

```
<span class="die">  
  <a href="/[...]/[...]/Lists/Cascade">Registration</a>
</span>
```

So I wanted to delete it but upon opening the form in SharePoint Designer 2013 I wasn't able to find any code that would resemble this.

Any pointers to where I should look?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your master page. Find the `<asp:Content>` which id is "`PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead`", see if you put the code in master page.

In addition, add "`?contents=1`" at the end of the url of the NewForm.aspx. for example,"`/sites/<site>/Lists/<list>/NewForm.aspx?contents=1`". It will open Web Part Page Maintenance page. Remove the web parts contain the script and check if it works.